# How to pytest a function that returns an array

Tags: python, pytest, assert

I have this function :

```
def getstocks(n):
    port = []
    for i in range(0, n):
        stock = input()
        port.append(stock)
    return port
```

My program asks n as an int input and then prompts the user to enter the same number of stock tickers.
For example if the input is 2, the user will have to enter 2 stock ticker symbols etc.

My question is how would I test this function with assert as the inputs for the stock tickers can be anything ?

Comment: you can test that the output `port` is not null and has the exact same number of elements  as `n`

Comment: You should test fixed data instead of using user input.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
def getstocks(n):
    port = []
    for i in range(0, n):
        stock = input()
        port.append(stock)
    assert len(port) == n
    return port
```

I'm not quite sure if that's what you wanted to test or whether you also want to test the user inputs. But yeah, you can modify this code to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use some combination of [pytest.mark.parametrize](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html) and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/GenevieveBuckley/efd16862de9e2fe7adfd2bf2bef93e02) which shows how to use Monkeypatch to pass input strings to a pytest function.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use pytest and monkeypatching the `input` function with a generator to have repeatable consecutive user inputs:

```py
import pytest
import builtins 


def getstocks(n):
    port = []
    for i in range(0, n):
        stock = input()
        port.append(stock)
    return port


@pytest.fixture
def mock_user_input(monkeypatch):

    def user_input():
        i = 0
        while True:
            yield i
            i += 1
            

    user = user_input()

    monkeypatch.setattr(builtins, 'input', lambda :  next(user))
    
def test_getstocks(mock_user_input):
    result = getstocks(10)
    assert result == list(range(10))
```